# Rails Active Record query: answered questions, ordered by answer date, not duplicates

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join, distinct

A question has many answers.

It is easy to find all questions that have been answered and order them by newest answer:

```
def self.answered
  joins(:answers).order('answers.created_at desc')
end
```

In the controller, I'd do @answered = Question.answered

But this returns duplicate records if a question has been answered more than once.

It's easy, on the other hand, to find distinct questions that have been answered, but only if I don't try to order them by their *answers'* created_at date:

```
def self.answered
  joins(:answers).select("DISTINCT questions.title")
end
```

(Let's just assume here that question titles are validated to be unique, so this results in all unique records).

**The problem:**

This query can't be ordered by an *answer's* "created_at" date, because I've selected only the *question's* title in my SQL select statement...

```
def self.answered
  joins(:answers).select("DISTINCT questions.title").order('answers.created_at desc')
end
```

results in this error (I'm using Postgres):

```
PGError: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
```

What it means, I guess, is it wants to see "answers.created_at" in that select DISTINCT statement.

The following looks like it would work if I wanted to order by questions.created_at, but that's not what I want:

```
def self.answered
  joins(:answers).select("DISTINCT(questions.title), questions.created_at").order('questions.created_at desc')
end
```

This is where my basic SQL knowledge conks out. How do I select distinct questions (only the ones with answers) and order them in descending order by their latest answer's created_at date?

I'd like to write it using Rails 3 Active Record queries, but straight SQL is fine. I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Anton's answer would be the preferred solution if we were talking about MySQL, but as you pointed out, it causes errors in PostgreSQL, since PG is a bit more restrictive in its select/grouping functions.

Here is how I was able to get it to work with PG:

```
def self.answered
 scoped.select("questions.title").group("questions.title").joins(:answers).having('MAX(answers.created_at) IS NOT NULL').order('MAX(answers.created_at) DESC')
end
```

Or, if you want to select the entire ActiveRecord rows for the questions, you can select/group by every column in `questions`:

```
def self.answered
 cols = self.column_names.collect{ |c| "#{table_name}.#{c}" }.join(',')
 scoped.select(cols).group(cols).joins(:answers).having('MAX(answers.created_at) IS NOT NULL').order('MAX(answers.created_at) DESC')
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use write as:

```
def self.answered
  joins(:answers).order("answers.created_at DESC").group("questions.id")
end
```

This will do exactly why you want :)

Comment: Just to note: you might pull that into a scope so that you can use on a collection of questions as well.

Comment: I don't understand why, but postgres complains: PGError: ERROR:  column "questions.title" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT     "questions".* FROM       "questions"  INNER JOIN ...
                   ^
: SELECT     "questions".* FROM       "questions"  INNER JOIN "answers" ON "answers"."question_id" = "questions"."id" GROUP BY  questions.id ORDER BY  answers.created_at DESC

Comment: And if I change questions.id to questions.title, it complains with the same message but asks for questions.id instead. It complains regardless of what attribute I'm asking for in the view. i.e., in the following, q.title could be anything: <% @just_answered.each do |q| %>
  <%= q.title %><br />
<% end %>

Comment: @SteveCotner I was experiencing the exact same problem as you when trying the above solution with PG. See my [solution below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8556361/366381) for how I was able to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

I can write the SQL solution for it. It would go as below:

```
select q.id "Qn-ID", q.question, q.created_at "Qn-CreatedAt", a.id "Ans-ID", a.answer, a.created_at "Ans-CreatedAt" from questions q, answers a where a.question_id = q.id and a.id in (select max(id) answer_id from answers group by question_id) order by "Ans-CreatedAt" desc
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This might end up being a little bit more efficient and extensible and should avoid issues where psql gripes about aggregate functions:

```
select questions.*, count(answers.id) as answer_count from questions join answers on answers.question_id=questions.id group by answers.question_id having answer_count > 0 order by answers.created_at desc
```

P.S. by extensible I meant, you can split it into Arel structure, and then break out scopes such as with_answers and answered to do your dirty work behind the scenes while keeping the rest clean and allowing you to add on more scopes later. :)

UPDATE: just posting the Arel way:

```
scope :answered, select('questions.*, count(answers.id) as answer_count').joins('join answers on answers.question_id=questions.id').group('answers.question_id').having('answer_count > 0').order('answers.created_at desc')
```

Comment: Never mind about the last comment; I misread it. But if I write it this way, it complains that column "answer_count" doesn't exist:   scope :answered, find_by_sql("select questions.*, count(answers.id) as answer_count from questions join answers on answers.question_id=questions.id group by answers.question_id having answer_count > 0 order by answers.created_at desc")

Comment: Just wondering: is all this just some PostgreSQL fiddle-faddle that I wouldn't have to deal with using MySQL?

Comment: So far, my best compromise is to make the model simple:   scope :answered, joins(:answers).order('answers.created_at desc') and to make controller a little bit limiting:     @just_answered = Question.answered.uniq[0..9]  I don't like this, of course, because it means I can't chain any more scopes onto @just_answered

Comment: You could try not selecting the count as a column and simply do having (count(answers.id)) > 0

Comment: I'm using MySQL and this works for me:

scope :answered, select('questions.*, count(answers.id) as answer_count').joins('join answers on answers.question_id=questions.id').group('answers.question_id').having('answer_count > 0').order('answers.created_at desc')